# Why are hockey pucks so indestructible?

Tags: forces

After watching a hockey puck be exposed to [extreme heat](https://youtu.be/_OHNneulrEk) as well as [extreme cold](https://youtu.be/mVBBdkM6-7c), the puck seems to end up in pretty good shape.  I can sort of understand the puck vs. hot ball of nickel since the area of contact is relatively small (and I've always been told that heat rises).  The other one, I'm confused why it fared so well.

In my experience, objects that are exposed to liquid nitrogen long enough become very brittle.  This leads to those object [shattering](https://youtu.be/0UjmqErytJc?t=1m44s) upon [impact](https://youtu.be/gAFzMor5aBQ?t=47s) if not [spontaneously](https://youtu.be/8ZRmEc1sjP8).  So what makes the hockey puck special to avoid such a shattering?

Comment: Note first, the heat was applied to a very small area so any effects will be minimal. Second, in the first third of the 'extreme cold' section, it *does* shatter into rather large pieces (quite visible at 0:35s mark).

Comment: @KyleKanos So why the shattering when cooled in glass vs. plastic?

Comment: The glass vs plastic might have something to do with insulation. Glass would conduct heat away better right? Or maybe that part of the video was time lapsed and the puck and the glass shattered due to prolonged exposure... did kind of look like the level rise/fell a few times didn't it? Anyways that puck was pretty dang indestructible.

Comment: Heat does not rise in general, that is only the case for heat transport in air or another fluid, for one object in direct contact with another object heat conduction will be an important mode of heat transfer and heat conduction does not care for the gravitation in the way convection in a fluid does. (Funfact aside: In water below 4°C but above the freezing point heat will "fall" in water due to convection, as the warmer water will have a higher density).

Comment: Related video:) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jxDycguIWXI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In my experience, objects that are exposed to liquid nitrogen long enough become very brittle. This leads to those object shattering upon impact if not spontaneously. So what makes the hockey puck special to avoid such a shattering?

Liquid nitrogen's boiling point is $-196\:\mathrm{Celsius}$ which is below the glass transition temperature ($T_g$) of *most* rubbers. Below that temperature an elastomer (rubber) becomes fragile like glass.

A puck is never exposed to that kind of temperature. The lowest will be in the order of about $-10\:\mathrm{Celsius}$ to $-20\:\mathrm{Celsius}$, which is well above the $T_g$ of most rubbers.

Pucks can take a lot mechanical battering and abrasion because they're made of specially formulated, sulphur vulcanised rubber, mostly based on high molecular weight natural rubber I believe. Optimal formulations can be obtained by statistically controlled designed experiments.

An important ingredient in black, reinforced vulcanised rubber is HAF (High Abrasion Furnace) carbon black, which as the name implies imparts high mechanical strength to the rubber vulcanisate.

Vulcanised rubber also resists high temperatures quite well because the three dimensional network of cross-links that connect the polymer chains means the material simply cannot melt (but it can of course degrade chemically at high temperatures).

Answer (score 0):

Because the material that pucks are made out of are 'vulcanized'.

This means that is it chemically changed to with sulphur to make it more durable.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the material properties / vulcanization?

Comment: The process joins the polymers of the rubber axially. That is to say that the sulphur atoms don't contribute to the chains of polymers but connect them adjacently.

[Here is a picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Vulcanization_of_POLYIsoprene_V.2.png)

Comment: "...changed to with sulphur..." grammar error? Also it's spelled "sulfur".

Comment: 'Sulphur' is English spelling, DavidSank. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfur